# How to check if a union in C has not been "initialized"?

Tags: c, null, unions

Can I check if union is null in c? For example:

```
union{ char * name, struct Something * something ... }someUnion;
```

Is there a way to check if no element has been initialized, without doing element vise check?

Thanks.

Comment: Asking "if a union is null" is a meaningless question in C.  A union cannot be null or non-null.  If it has an element which is a pointer or an integer, than that member can be compared with null or zero respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, under the conditions that all members of the union are of pointer type or a integral type and with initialization you mean a value which is not NULL has been assigned, it is sufficient to check *one* element for NULL.

```
union { 
    char * name;
    struct Something * something; } someUnion;

if (someUnion.name != 0) {
    // here you know that someUnion.something is not NULL too.
    // You don't know if it has been initialized as char*
    // or as struct something* though. Presumeably since
    // it is a unionboth interpretations make some sense. 
}
```

Comment: it could be null by chance. you have a probability of 1/256 of this happening every time the app runs

Comment: @Gir So what? Actually it will be 0 "by chance" even more often, because newly allocated memory pages are initialized by OS with 0. How does a "0" which is initialized by the OS differ from a 0 initialized by the user?

Answer (score 6):

No, not without adding a specific flag for that purpose. For example:

```
struct someStruct {
    int initialized;
    union {
        char *name;
        struct Something *something;
    };
};
```

You could even store a flag instead of `initialized` that indicates which kind of data the union contains. This is commonly called a [Tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: What if every union was initialized as `u = {0}`; could it then be safe to `someU == defaultU`?

Comment: @pst: `{0}` may be a valid value for one or more of the union members. For example, in the question both `name` and `something` could have `NULL` as a valid value, since they are both pointers.

Comment: `union foo obj = { 0 };` is always valid; it initializes the first member to the appropriate zero value for the type (defined recursively if necessary). As of C99, you can also use designated initializers: `union foo obj = { .initialized = 0 };`. But note that you can't specify an initializer in the union definition.

Comment: @pst, the default initializer `{0}` only initializes the first member of the union. If you have other members that are wider than your first member, they might not be properly initialized.

Comment: @Greg: but you have only shifted the problem: how do you ensure that `someStruct`'s instance is initialized?

Comment: @Vlad: The question specifically asked about a union. The problem with checking a union is you don't know which union member was last set, but you *do* know that a struct member will always be there when you look for it.