# Is it possible to use cppcheck to check if a union has been initialized?

Tags: c, union, cppcheck

Recently I found a mistake in my code. it's about an union type local variable has not been initialized, so that there will be unexpected data in the memory.

I'm curious if there is a way to use static analysis tool such as [Cppcheck](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/) to find similar problems elsewhere in my existing projects. After learning how to use Cppcheck, I found that there's only some MISRA-C style warning such as `"The union keyword should not be used"` in the code section where I used union local variable. So my question is, is it possible to use Cppcheck to check if the union has been initialized?

Thanks for your time.

Here's my demo code:

```
typedef unsigned char UBYTE;
typedef unsigned short UWORD;

typedef union
{
    UWORD  word;
    struct
    {       
        UBYTE Lbyte;
        UBYTE Hbyte;    
    }byte;
    struct
    {
        UWORD LBLbit4:4;
        UWORD LBHbit4:4;
        UWORD HBLbit4:4;
        UWORD HBHbit4:4;
    }bit4;
    struct
    {
         UWORD bit0:1;
         UWORD bit1:1;
         UWORD bit2:1;
         UWORD bit3:1;
         UWORD bit4:1;
         UWORD bit5:1;
         UWORD bit6:1;
         UWORD bit7:1;
         UWORD bit8:1;
         UWORD bit9:1;
         UWORD bit10:1;
         UWORD bit11:1;
         UWORD bit12:1;
         UWORD bit13:1;
         UWORD bit14:1;
         UWORD bit15:1;
         
    }bit;   
}uuWORD;

static UWORD UpdateBit12(UWORD flag)
{
    uuWORD data;

    if(flag == (UWORD)1)
    {
        data.bit.bit12 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        data.bit.bit12 = 0;
    }

    return data.word;
}
```

Comment: btw I found a way called tagged union in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542925/how-to-check-if-a-union-in-c-has-not-been-initialized). It seems to be a good option to prevent my mistake.

Comment: An even better option is to **never** declare a variable without initialising it to a known value. Seeing `uuWORD data;` should be as repugnant to a coder's eyes as can be imagined... Establish good habits and you'll save yourself lots of grief (without needing support from auxiliary programs.)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/ says " - using uninitialized local variables" so consider filing a bug if it doesn't catch this.  Consider stdint.h types instead of those first two typedefs.  If you are on Linux valgrind is great at this.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, it is better not to use a union for this purpose. It you use shifts and bit masks instead, the code turns portable and perhaps faster too.

Comment: In extension to Lundin's comment, the order and arrangement of bit fields are not defined by the C standard, they are implementation-defined and can vary between compilers. Concerning the speed I think it does not make a difference, look at the generated code.

Comment: According to the feedback from Cppcheck forum, they used to take this as an issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/general/thread/27d553054a/